# ¿Por qué no dibuja el cuadrado completo? Java Graphics

Tags: java, java-swing

He creado una clase Cuadro que hereda de JComponent. 
Al momento de pintar el cuadrado que necesito me dibuja esto:

[image: Error Java Swing]

El problema es que me dibuja la mitad del cuadrado y no he sabido resolverlo.

A continuación dejó mi código.

Cuadro.java:

```
public class Cuadro extends JComponent {
    
    public Cuadro(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        setLocation(x, y);
        setSize(w, h);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    
}
```

Home.java:

```
public class Home extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Home() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }                    

    private void formKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                              
        Cuadro c = new Cuadro(10, 10, 50, 50);
        pnl.add(c);
        pnl.repaint();
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel pnl;              
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta esta muy bien estructurada. Mira [ask] para mas tips sobre como preguntar. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Intenta de éste modo: `g.drawRect(0,0,getWidth()-1,getHeight()-1);`

Comment: @JohnnyTB He tardado en darme cuenta pero tu respuesta me ha funcionado. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se me occuren al menos 2 opciones para hacer esto, la primera es hacer lo que dijo @JohnnyTH en los comentarios.

El panel donde se agregue el cuadro debe tener un layout nulo, ya que le estas definiendo propiedades como setSize y setLocation, que solo las leerá un layout nulo o absoluto. Si quieres que el cuadro se comporte como cualquier otro componente, debes definir un tamaño real para este cuadro, tamaño mínimo, máximo y preferido; obviamente todo depende de lo que quieras hacer.

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Titulo");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        
        frame.setLayout(null);
        
        Cuadro cuadro = new Cuadro(10, 10, 150, 150);
        frame.add(cuadro);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}
```

Cuadro

```
public class Cuadro extends JComponent {
    
    public Cuadro(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        setLocation(x, y);
        setSize(w, h);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);
    }
    
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la segunda opciones es mas fácil aun, y es una de las que yo estoy utilizando en un proyecto para eso específicamente. Simplemente utiliza un borde.

```
public Cuadro(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    setLocation(x, y);
    setSize(w, h);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
}
```

Java te proporciona un montón de bordes que puedes ver el la clase BorderFactory, algunos mas complejos que otros, pero sin duda funcionan mejor y te ahorran trabajo de pintura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ninguno te convence puedes crear el tuyo. Ademas los bordes tienen la ventaja de que son reutilizables, es decir, no es necesario que heredes del componentes para aplicarlo específicamente en el método paint o paintComponent, con un simple setBorder lo tendrás en cualquier componente.

Comment: El código que me has presentado funciona bien. pero tengo otro problema. Al añadir otro cuadro sólo me dibuja el primero.

Comment: Has cambiado las coordenadas xy del segundo cuadrado? El layout nulo pintara arriba del otro cuadrado si no cambias las coordenadas.

Comment: Sí, son diferentes coordenadas :/

Comment: Me parece que la respuesta dada por JFrame resuelve la duda inicial. Lo del segundo cuadro debería tener su propia pregunta pues si se queda solo en los comentarios es más difícil que alguien más aporte soluciones al problema

Comment: He tardado en darme cuenta pero sí, sí funciona.